# When is $\mathbb{E}[z^T\Sigma z]$ monotone for an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, lyapunov-functions

Consider the stochastic differential equation

$$d Z_t = M Z_t dt + dB_t,$$

where $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is assumed to have eigenvalues that have negative real parts, $B_t$ is $n$-dimensional spherical brownian motion.

The solution of this SDE is given by

$$ Z_t = \exp(Mt)Z_0 + \int_0^t \exp(M(t-s)) dB_s$$

and has the distribution $$Z_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\exp(Mt)Z_0,\int_0^t \exp(M(t-s))\exp(M^T(t-s))ds\right).$$

Now, consider the function $$f(z) = z^T\Sigma z.$$
I am trying to understand for what choice of $\Sigma$ positive (semi-)definite we have that $\mathbb{E}[Z_t^T\Sigma Z_t]$ is decreasing.

In the case of a deterministic equation, this yields to the Lyapunov equation, such that all $\Sigma$ that solve $$M\Sigma + \Sigma M^T = - Q,$$ for some positive definite $Q$, yield a Lyapunov function for the system
But in the stochastic case, we obtain an additional term that results from the fact that

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z_t^T\Sigma Z_t] = \mathbb{E}[Z_t]^T\Sigma  \mathbb{E}[Z_t]  + \operatorname{tr}[\Sigma C(t)]$$

with $C(t) = \operatorname{Cov}[Z_t]$.

Differentiating yields

$$ 2\mathbb{E}[Z_t]  \Sigma M \mathbb{E}[Z_t] + \operatorname{tr}[\Sigma (M C(t) + C(t)M^T + I_n)]$$

And then I'm stuck. Theoretically, $C(\infty)^{-1}$ should work, but I also don't know how to show that.
So, any help on how to determine the general form of the solutions would be appreciated!

**Edit**:   After some thoughts, and also considering the answer below, it seems that one has to consider the initial conditions carefully.

As an example, consider $Z_0=0$. Then we have $\frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[f(Z_t)]\vert_0 = \operatorname{tr}[\Sigma]$, so this should also hold in some neighborhood of $0$. Intuitively, the noise has to 'spread out' first from the initial delta distribution.

Comment: I assume $A$ is $\Sigma$? Anyway, I don't trust my Ito calculus skills to post an answer, but if I sketched it right, this time you need your Q to have eigenvalues lower bounded by $tr(\Sigma)$ (as opposed to 0). Not sure though.

Comment: @E-A yes you're right, that $A$ was a $\Sigma$. Also, there was some additional identity term missing in the derivative. How do you obtain your result? Especially with the time dependent $C(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, I am unsure of the answer as I am unsure of my multivariate Ito calculus, but here it goes:

Here, we can use Ito's formula, namely, for any $f$, we can find the change in the value of the function to be

$$df = (\mu_t \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{\sigma^2_t}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2})dt + ...dB_t $$

Now, in expectation, the terms containing $dB_t$ go away, and we are now left with

$$\mathbb{E}[\mu_t \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{\sigma^2_t}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}]$$

The first term is the same as in the deterministic case, which gives us

$ \mathbb{E}[Z_t^\top (\Sigma + \Sigma^\top) M Z_t ]$  for the first term

We note that the Hessian of $f$ is constant. As such, the second term simply reduces to trace of $\Sigma$. As such, a sufficient condition should be to ensure that

$x^\top (\Sigma + \Sigma^\top)M x + tr(\Sigma) < 0$.

Comment: I have to admit that I have not thought about doing it this way round, i.e. by not explicitly evaluating the expectation and rather appeal to it's monotonicity. But I think this sufficient condition will never work, since by plugging in small enough $x$ we should be able to not have it fulfilled everywhere. Or was the argument something else?

Comment: (Which also seems to apply to my form above now that I have a second look... so maybe one has to be more careful about the analysis)

Comment: You seem right on both counts; yeah, maybe ping this post again (by writing a comment here) when you figure out the Lyapunov condition for the deterministic case. That might help this case too.